# Is it possible to only send some windows key shortcuts into RDP?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm using vmconnect/rdp to connect to a Win10 hyper-v VM from a Win10 computer. Most windows key shortcuts I'd like to be able to send into the RDP session, but there's some I'd like to be sent to my physical computer.

Hyper-v settings has an option to send windows key combinations to either the physical computer or to the VM, but it's an all-or-nothing situation.

Altnernatively I'd like to be able to bind my left windows key to send into the RDP session while the right windows key sends to my physics computer.

Are either possible?